# mypy: "Item of Union has no attribute" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Trying to learn to type hint in Python. Given these two functions:

```
from typing import Union, TextIO


def myfunc_ok(file: TextIO):
    mydump = file.read()
    print(mydump)


def myfunc_error(file: Union[str, TextIO]):
    mydump = file.read()
    print(mydump)
```

First one is ok to mypy, but it complains about the second one with an error

```
Item "str" of "Union[str, TextIO]" has no attribute "read"
```

Am I using type hinting incorrenctly in this case?
(Using python3.7 with mypy 0.610, also tested with py3.6)

Comment: What is your confusion? The ``str`` type *does not* have a read method. Using ``.read()`` on a variable that *may be* ``str`` is therefore wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your signature

```
def myfunc_error(file: Union[str, TextIO]):
    ...
```

says that `file` parameter can be `str` or `TextIO`, after that in function body you are trying to access `.read` attribute of `file` object, but in case of `file` being `str` there is no such attribute hence the error.

You have at least 3 possibilities here:

- do not support case with `file` being of type `str` and replace `Union[str, TextIO]` with `TextIO`
- add explicit type checking using [`isinstance` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) in function body like

  ```
  import io
  ...
  def myfunc_error(file: Union[str, TextIO]):
      if isinstance(file, io.TextIOWrapper):
          mydump = file.read()
      else:
          # assuming ``file`` is a required object already
          mydump = file
      print(mydump)
  ```

  this may become difficult to maintain in the long term
- write 2 different functions for given task: one for `str` parameter and one for `TextIO` parameter like

  ```
  def myfunc_error_str_version(file: str):
      mydump = file
      print(mydump)

  def myfunc_error_text_io_version(file: TextIO):
      mydump = file.read()
      print(mydump)
  ```

  this may cause a lot of naming problems (but it depends on the use-case)

The last approach can be improved using [`functools.singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch): in short this will allow us to define a [generic function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generic-function) & use a name `myfunc_error` with overloads called based on the type of first positional argument (`file` in our case):

```
import io
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import TextIO


@singledispatch
def myfunc_error(file: str):
    mydump = file
    print(mydump)

# using ``typing.TextIO`` will not work because it's just an interface for type annotations,
# "real" types are located at ``io`` module
@myfunc_error.register(io.TextIOWrapper)
def _(file: TextIO):
    mydump = file.read()
    print(mydump)
```

**Note**: we can use any name we want instead of `_` except `myfunc_error`, for the latter `mypy` will raise a name conflict error.

Comment: My confusion here was assuming mypy was not smart enough to test if function call (read in this case) was inside a isinstance test of the correct type... Really astounding... The aim is for my function to support either a file name or a file object and indeed it would include an isinstance test (which I removed to simplify the example)